# How can I modify a HTTP header in Android

Tags: android, api, http-headers, processing

I am trying to make a Football Data API. I need to modify my http header like this: 
thanks for registering for an API authentication token. Please modify your client to use a HTTP header named "X-Auth-Token" with the underneath personal token as value.

Your API token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I tried it for 2 days but I can't get it working. (I'm sorry I'm new to programming). This is my code:

```
PImage button;

long Team; int shortName; int squadValue;

String url1 = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/"; String
teamNumber = "66"; String url = url1 + teamNumber;

int refreshDelay = 5000; long lastTime;

void setup(){ background(#00DB17); size(1440, 2560); lastTime = 
millis()-refreshDelay;

fill(255); button = loadImage("voetbal.png"); imageMode(CENTER);
image(button,720,500);

fill(255); textSize(100); text("PRESS TO SEE TEAM", 300,350); }

void draw(){

if ((millis() - lastTime) > refreshDelay) { lastTime = millis();
if(mousePressed){
          if(mouseX>(500) && mouseX <(1040) && mouseY>(490) && mouseY<(790)){
            getInfo();
            fill(255);
            textSize(100);
            text("Team ID: "+teamNumber, 10, 1000);
            text("Team: "+Team, 10, 1300);
            text("Short Name: "+shortName, 10, 1600);
            text("Squad Market Value: "+squadValue, 10, 1900);
          }
    }    } }

void getInfo(){   try{
      JSONObject info = loadJSONObject(url); 
      Team = info.getLong("name"); 
      shortName = info.getInt("shortName"); 
      squadValue = info.getInt("squadMarketValue"); 

   } catch (Exception e) {
       println("rats...");
       } }
```

Can someone please help me? How do I do this in android mode?